# three.js How to position one object beside another (global world position)

Tags: three.js, position, global

I load one object with objloader on my scene, later, I load a second object on my scene, but I want to change it's absolute position to another side of my first object.

All position of both object is relative to local (0,0,0).

How I can change it's global position ?

Comment: Can you add some relevant code? Getting help may be easier that way.

Comment: This don't work but the idea is here : object1.position.set(object2.position.copy); I tried with matrixWorld.getPosition() or localToWorld it's always return it's relative position (0,0,0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer:

```
object1.position.copy(object2.matrixWorld.getPosition());
```

Comment: I can't believe how long it took me to find this answer. Thank you!

Comment: .getPosition() is deprecated. Now you are told to use Vector3.setFromMatrixPosition( matrix ) instead if you try to call it.

Answer (score 8):

The answer that davincy posted is now out of date. In my version of threejs it responded with this warning:

> THREE.Matrix4: .getPosition() has been removed. Use
>   Vector3.setFromMatrixPosition( matrix ) instead.

So then you'll need to replace it with the following:

```
objectA.position.setFromMatrixPosition( objectB.matrixWorld );
```

wherein objectB is the object that is in the scene and the object that you want objectA to copy its position from.

Answer (score 0):

Every object you can put into a scene has a "position" property, which is a three-dimensional vector. You can simply change its x/y/z values.

For example, given your object is called "mesh":

```
mesh.position.x += 1; //you need re-render if you change something in the object after adding to the scene
yourScene.add(mesh);
```

This will move the object one "unit" on the scene. This means you can do that:

```
mesh2.position.x = mesh1.position.x + 1;
yourScene.add(mesh1); 
yourScene.add(mesh2);
```

Here you can check other properties and methods available for objects you can put on THREE.js scene:

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D

Comment: I know that, but I want to get the position of my other object for moving this object beside it...

Comment: Could you please show some code you have? It would be much easier to help you. The basic principle is to access object's position vector, this is the only place three.js stores the position. You can also access the scene if you don't have a direct handle to the object, go through scene's children and find the one you want. Again though, without the code it might be difficult to guess what is the problem you are struggling with.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any code because all I try is not working. Always return 0. Basically I try to find the world x position (on the scene) of one object to set it to another object. You know ?

Comment: Show the code you have which is not working. This place is exactly for fixing code which does not do what expected! :)